# Matlab: conformal maps for image distortion with imwarp

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using imtransform to distort images with conformal maps as proposed in [exploring a conformal mapping](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/exploring-a-conformal-mapping.html). It works fine but Matlab shows a warning that imtransform is not recommended and imwarp should be used instead but the transfer from imtransform to imwarp is difficult. Could someone transfer the distortion process with intransform [a] in a geometric transformation object for imwarp?

[a] This transforms an RGB image C into T

```
conformal = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], @conformalInverse, []);
T = imtransform(C, conformal, 'bicubic', 'UData', uData,'VData', vData, 'XData', xData,'YData', yData, 'Size', [cm_out_h cm_out_w], 'FillValues', FillValue);
```

with the conformal map formula defined in conformalInverse.m like:

```
function U = conformalInverse(X, ~)
%#codegen
U = [zeros(size(X))];
Z = complex(X(:,1),X(:,2));
a = 2; W = (1./(4 * Z.^a - 1));
U(:,2) = imag(W);
U(:,1) = real(W);
```

and some parameter value examples like:

```
uData     = [ -1.25   1.25];  % Bounds for REAL(w)
vData     = [  0.75  -0.75];  % Bounds for IMAG(w)
xData     = [ -2.00   2.00];  % Bounds for REAL(z)
yData     = [  2.00  -2.00];  % Bounds for IMAG(z)
cm_out_h  = 3000;             % h of output image
cm_out_w  = 3000;             % w of output image
FillValue = 0;                % color definition to fill possible empty areas; here 0 == black
```

Comment: I got the hint that every parameter except custom geometric transformation could be changed in imwarp. From this one could conclude that distortion with conformal maps are not possible with imwarp if there is no workaround. If this is true, I would call this a regression in the development of Matlab.